# celery task with routing key on SQS

Tags: django-celery, amazon-sqs, celery-task

I have a django celery set up, and I'm switching over from rabbitmq to use SQS as the broker. I'm finding that my tasks decorated with a routing_key value are not producing messages in the broker?

Set up is:

```
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    "default": {
        "exchange": "default", 
        "binding_key": "default"},
    "sentry": {
        "exchange": "default",
        "binding_key": "sentry"},
}

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = "default"
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = "default"
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = "direct"
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = "default"
```

task is defined as

```
@task(routing_key = 'sentry', ignore_result = True)
def doSomething():
  print "Hello"

doSomething.delay() # No message is produced
```

Everything routes fine into the default queue. Unusually everything works fine with rabbit mq?

The Amazon SQS console is showing the queue 'sentry', but no messages are sent to it (I'm not sure what created the queue)

Bonus: unusually, when I first tried this out (about 4 hours ago), some messages did appear to make it to the sentry queue? What could have possibly caused this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example with one change. Instead of defining the routing key in the task decorator, I defined the queue in the call to the task. And I changed the call from "delay" to "apply_async"

So my code looks like

```
@task
def doSomething():
    print "Hello"


doSomething.apply_async(queue='sentry')
```